# How do I search a column for words that are in different positions

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to update the field where the names contains whatever the user typed in. I used wildcard and it worked for most names. It doesn't work for some names because in the column the last name comes first followed by the middle name and then their last name. So, when users typed in the first name and last name that the query cannot locate the name because the order of the name entered is not correct. How do I make it in such a way that the order of the names typed in my form does not matter and users would still be able to look for the field and update regardless.

```
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click()
     Dim db As DAO.Database
     Dim qdf As QueryDef
     Dim sql As String

     Set db = CurrentDb()
     Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("UpdateSM")

     sqlString = "UPDATE KissFlowtbl SET SM = '" & Me.txtSM & "' WHERE AM Like  '*" & Me.txtAM & "*'  "
     qdf.sql = sqlString

      If Nz(Me.txtSM, "") = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter SM name"
        Resume Exit_Update
      ElseIf Nz(Me.txtAM, "") = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter AM name"
        Resume Exit_Update
      End If

     DoCmd.OpenQuery "UpdateSM"

      qdf.Close
      CurrentDb.Close

Exit_Update:
Exit Sub

Exit_UpdateEmail:
If Err.Number = 2501 Then
    Resume Exit_Update
Else
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_Update
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a sample.

you should spit the the string value from Me.txtAM by space.

```
    name = Split(Me.txtAM, " ")
```

rearranged the the value by your needs and store it to variables. you need to check first the length of the array.

```
    name1 = name(0)
    name2 = name(1)
    name3 = name(2)

    sqlString = "UPDATE KissFlowtbl SET SM = '" & Me.txtSM & "' WHERE AM Like  '*" & name1 & "*'  " AND AM Like  '*" & name2 & "*'  " AND AM Like  '*" & name3 & "*'  "
```

Comment: Len(name()) - 1

Comment: name = Split(Me.txtAM) for this line, I got an error message saying I can't put this in an array

Comment: name = Split(Me.txtAM, " ")
split by space but you need to trim first the Me.txtAM

Comment: Trim( Me.txtAM )

Comment: I got the same error saying i can't assign it to an array

Comment: Me.txtAM.text.Split(" ")

Comment: Me.txtAM.Text.Split(","c)